# Class to filter URLs for Spring Boot does not build

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, filter

This is a Spring Boot Java project using Maven. 
If I remove the @Configuration annotation from WebConfig, the application builds but the class seems to be ignored. If I include it, the app fails with this message:

> Error starting Tomcat context. Exception:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException. Message:
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DispatcherType cannot be cast to
>   javax.servlet.DispatcherType. Application run failed.

How can I properly set up Spring Boot to use filters?

Here is the main app class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GetJobDetailsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(GetJobDetailsApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GetJobDetailsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MainRESTController {

    // inject via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message:test}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

Here is the WebConfig where I set up the filters:

```
import org.owasp.filters.ClickjackFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DispatcherType;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter;
import java.util.EnumSet;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean clickjackFilterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(clickjackFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/");
    registration.addInitParameter("paramName", "paramValue");
    registration.setName("clickjackFilter");
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
  }

  @Bean(name = "clickjackFilter")
  public ClickjackFilter clickjackFilter() {
    return new ClickjackFilter();
  }

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/");
    return registration;
  }
}
```

And here is the clickjackFilter class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ClickjackFilter implements Filter {

  private String mode = "DENY";

  /**
   * Add X-FRAME-OPTIONS response header to tell IE8 (and any other browsers who
   * decide to implement) not to display this content in a frame. For details, please
   * refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/sdl/archive/2009/02/05/clickjacking-defense-in-ie8.aspx.
   */
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    res.addHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", mode);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    String configMode = filterConfig.getInitParameter("mode");
    if (configMode != null) {
      mode = configMode;
    }
  }
}
```

Dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
         tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could be the POM dependency scope. Might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799295/classcastexception-dispatcherservlet-cannot-be-cast-to-servlet

Comment: Thanks, I will try and tomorrow I will post the pom.xml but I suspect the way I am setting up the filters and configuring Spring Boot is wrong.

Comment: I think import is wrong. `FilterRegistrationBean` require `javax.servlet.DispatcherType` not `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DispatcherType`

Comment: Do you know what name and value should be passed to the addInitParameter call? Is anything fine as long as the name is unique? registration.addInitParameter("paramName", "paramValue");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closer look on your stacktrace, can you try setting the DispatcherType as

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.lang.Enum<DispatcherType>
        javax.servlet.DispatcherType
```

since the `FilterRegistrationBean` expects a parameter of type `javax.servlet.DispatcherType` for the set `setDispatcherTypes()`

Or you can directly register the filter beans by using the annotations like :

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE -1)
@Component
public class ABCFilter implements Filter {
  ------
}
```

In spring boot normally you configure the filters like :

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired 
  HandlerInterceptor customInjectedInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(...)
    ... 
    registry.addInterceptor(customInjectedInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
  }
}
```

or if you are using Spring 5x then :

```
@Configuration
public WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // ...
}
```

By doing this we are essentially customizing the spring boot auto configuration beans , so that springboot can still auto configure all of the other things.If you are using springboot consider removing @EnableWebMvc and using springboot's autoconfiguration.

Comment: Thank you, I added the dependencies from the pom.xml file to the question. I am using Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE. To use Spring 5x, do I need to add another dependency like this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.0.1.RELEASE?

Comment: Changing the import type to javax.servlet.DispatcherType worked! 
Do you know what name and value should be passed to the addInitParameter call? Is anything fine as long as the name is unique? registration.addInitParameter("paramName", "paramValue");

Comment: Digging into it, I see that setDispatcherTypes in AbstractFilterRegistrationBean takes an EnumSet<DispatcherType> and the enum DispatcherType is in package javax.servlet.