# DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (ClassCastException)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a similar problem to the one here [DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799295/classcastexception-dispatcherservlet-cannot-be-cast-to-servlet)
 which is when running a new Spring MVC project using Eclipse.
However, all the answers suggest a solution using Maven and I'm not using Maven.

I searched for a day for this problem but no solution.

```
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.4]
Mar 22, 2021 9:59:10 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took 
[447] milliseconds.

Mar 22, 2021 9:59:10 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for 
this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. 
Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.


 Mar 22, 2021 9:59:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: Marking servlet [dispatcher] as unavailable

 Mar 22, 2021 9:59:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
 SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/spring-mvc-demo] threw load() exception
 java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot 
 be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
 is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader 
 @62e70ea3; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader 
 @8bd1b6a)
 
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:984)
```

Comment: Looks like you’re running Tomcat 10 with a version of Spring that doesn’t support Tomcat 10. All the JavaEE classes were renamed when it became JakartaEE. It looks like no version of Spring yet supports the new namespace - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25354. Use Tomcat 9.

Comment: I use Tomcat 10, Spring 5.29 and Eclipse Enterprise 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Comment: So do you suggest downgrading Spring or Tomcat?

Comment: and by the way I'm using a code from 2017

Comment: How would downgrading Spring help? Use Tomcat 9.

Comment: sorry I don't use Maven

Comment: Spring only supports, at the moment, JavaEE. You are using Tomcat10 which is using JakartaEE and thus isn't going to work. YOu will need to use tomcat9 (which is JavaEE and not JakartaEE).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Spring (and Spring Boot) currently only support JavaEE and not JakartaEE. Which means that it will only run on/with JavaEE compatible servers. [Tomcat10](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) is an implementation of the JakartaEE specification which currently [isn't supported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+jakarta).

The only solution is to downgrade to Tomcat 9.

Comment: Strictly speaking I suppose you could also try Tomcat’s conversion tool. But it doesn’t look production ready yet.

Comment: Is this (Spring Boot not supporting Jakarta) still the case?

Comment: Yes. Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3 support JakartaEE which are expected at the end of the year.

Comment: thanks so much for pointing this out. I added jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0 to my  pom and things were fine once more.